# Performing a username lookup before registering a User while conforming to REST philosophy

Tags: rest

I have a REST Service based on Spring MVC. JSON is the only interchange format for any client to talk to this service.

I'm working on implementing a user registration workflow. So I have created an endpoint (/register, payload=User object in JSON) that accepts the User entity and does it's thing. So I'm transferring the state of an object which makes me content about adhering to the REST philosophy (I think).

My question is: Before I can register a user, I need to check if ther username is already used up. So I can create a new endpoint /register/username/
But this idea sounds bad and not RESTful at all as I'm using the endpoint to perform an action, not transfer of state. And this sounds like I'm invoking a method to perform an action (remote RPC). How can I re think this in terms of REST?

Answer (score 6):

> I'm using the endpoint to perform an action, not transfer of state.

Actually, you are transferring state.  The client is sending the proposed new user entity to the server.  The server has its own rules to enforce, however, so it must refuse to create a user if their unique identifier already exists.

There is already an HTTP error code for that.  As @tom pointed out, `the 409 Conflict` response code is acceptable for that.  It basically means `What you asked me to do is perfectly legal in from your standpoint.  I am simply unable to fulfill your request because it is in conflict with something outside of your control` versus some of the other response codes which focus on inappropriate client requests.

As far as your concern about using REST to perform an action in this case, I don't agree, but I am glad you are thinking about that.  I have seen developers create "REST services" named things like `GET /whatever/updateWidget`, which is clearly not a RESTful way of thinking.

You are performing an action only in the sense that you are creating a new resource.  But that resource is based on the state you transferred.  You have to create it somehow.

As long as you return a meaningful error code like `409`, I do not see any problems with your approach whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you. If I return 409 Conflict, How can the client decipher if the conflict occured because the username is already used up or if the password criteria is unacceptable to the Server?? How can the server construct the response so that the client gets the necessary information it needs to present to the user?:

Comment: Renaming the endpoint from "register" to "users" should be enough, right?

Comment: @user1324816: 409 expects you to add to the response body ["enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10).

Answer (score 2):

When a client attempts to add a duplicate, I would return a [409 Conflict](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10).  A 400 bad request (with explanation error in response) would also be fine and is probably more common practice.

However, the jury is out on this one.  REST doesn't make it clear what to do in these situations.  See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes-for-failed-validation-or-invalid-duplicate

Answer (score 2):

For starters, and I think you're onto this already, don't invent new verbs and stuff them into the tree.  If you find yourself wanting to do that, stop and ask yourself where in the model the data should fit, then `POST` it there.

Creating a new user should be an operation you do against the same part of the tree you use to get at the ones that already exist.  For example, you'd `GET /users/lanceboyle` to retrieve Lance Boyle's user information, so you should be `POST`ing to the same place to create a new one (e.g., `POST /users/duanepipe`).

Your situation seems to hit the major points for a return code of `409`.  From [RFC 7231](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7231.txt) (emphasis mine):

> The request could not be completed due to a **conflict with the current state of the resource**.

If there's already data in `/users/warrenpease`, then its state is "existing."  Trying to `POST` a second copy to the same location conflicts with that state because you can't create a new one of what already exists.

> This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the **user might be able to resolve the conflict** and resubmit the request.

Again, the user (requester) can resolve this problem by picking a different user name and `POST`ing it to a location that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user name uniqueness check to be performed as part of creating an account, you could let "POST /accounts" return 409 if an account for that user name already exists. See [the overview of HTTP status codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). In the response body, you could return an appropriate error message. If you have a convention for specifying exactly which field is invalid in the error response, then you could use that convention to indicate that the user name is causing a problem (e.g. to highlight that field on the screen). Example 409 response:

```
{
    "message" : "Unable to register new account",
    "errorFields" : [
        { "field" : "userName", "message" : "An account with this user name already exists" },
        { "field" : "password", "message" : "Password too weak" }
    ]
}
```

However, I am rather thinking in a totally different direction. It is common in such situations, that the client needs to check explicitly for a duplicate user name *before* attempting to create an account, for example as soon as the user leaves the user name field. In that case, the client app should use the HTTP method 'HEAD'. See [the HTTP methods spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4). The server returns 200 if an account for that user name already exists and 404 if the account does not exist.

Suppose /accounts represents the collection of accounts and /account/xxx represents an individual account for user name xxx, then the client should do HEAD /accounts/xxx to check if user xxx already has an account. Ideally, the client does not simply append "/xxx" to "/accounts", but uses a templated link, /accounts/{username}, provided by another resource.

I would not put user names in the path, though. I would use technical keys instead, e.g. /accounts/*accountID* represents an individual account, where *accountID* is a technical key. In that case, if the client app has to check if user name xxx is already in use, it can do HEAD /accounts?userName=xxx (again, another resource should provide a templated link to do this).